# Kolmogorov's paper defining Bayesian sufficiency

Tags: statistics, reference-request, bayesian

I'm looking for a translation to either English, French or German of Kolmogorov's Russian paper

*[Kolmogorov, A. (1942). Sur l’estimation statistique des paramètres de la loi de Gauss. Bull. Acad. Sci. URSS Ser. Math. 6, 3–32.](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=3752&option_lang=eng)*

This seminal, oft-cited paper (e.g. in Lehmann and Romano's Testing Statistical Hypotheses (2008) p. 20 and in Blackwell and Ramamoorthi's A Bayes But Not Classically Sufficient Statistic (1982) p. 1) originated the concept of Bayesian Sufficiency.

Translations to other Romance languages or to Dutch are also welcome.

Comment: Do you have the russian title of the article? It seems the article has a french summary, but it didn't help much for a google search.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: [Here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=3752&option_lang=eng) you go. The full text.

Comment: If my level of Russian was better, I'd translate it for you. But right now, it would be at the rate of one sentence a day. Surely, some translation must exist, maybe not a publically accessible one. Let's see who comes around. You might be more lucky asking on [stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/?as=1). Maybe even on [russian.SE](http://russian.stackexchange.com/?as=1)

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Thanks.